# Duplicates in URL using REQUEST_URI on included files

Tags: php, url

I have a content `<div>` in which I include different PHP files depending on the `$_GET` value...For example i have `/index.php?type=foo&action=bar` . I am trying to include a PHP file which contains some table data and simple pagination which looks like this

`$paginate .= "<a href='$target&page=$prevPage'>previous page</a>";`

Where `$target = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];`. It works how i want it to with the exception that every time i go to the next/previous page the URL gets duplicates. For example:
`/index.php?type=foo&action=bar&page=2&page=3&page=4&page=3&page=2` and so on... Using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` gets me back to `\index.php` without the extra `$_GET` parameters

I realize why this is happening, but is there a nice workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$target = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
$target = preg_replace('/&page=\d*/',"",$target);
$paginate .= "<a href='$target&page=$prevPage'>previous page</a>";
```

Better you give page name :

Change :

```
$target = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
```

To :

```
$target = 'your_page.php';
```

Comment: I do not want this, since the content of my included file is dynamic and i will want to use the same file on a different page e.g.: `\index.php?type=blabla&action=blabla` , i want to keep everything before the `&page=`

Comment: Edited the answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that using user input to create URIs may be a security issue.

In my opinion, you will have to decode the request - to an array for example. Then you can edit the values and create a new query string.

```
$cur = $_GET;
$cur['page'] = 7;
$new = array();
foreach ($cur as $key=>$val) {
  // Possily you need to remove magic quotes, here
  $new[] = url_encode($key).'='.url_encode($val);
}
$target = 'index.php?'.implode('&', $new);
```

I also suggest to use fixed file names. Using the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] only makes sense when the script name is likely to change. Usually, this will not be the case.

Also consider to collect pre-specified variables from the $_GET or $_REQUEST. This avoids some security issued.